# pyzk how to get the result of live capture

Tags: python-3.x, zkteco

`: 1495 : 2020-02-11 11:55:00 (1, 0)`

Here is my sample result but then when I'm trying to split it gives me error

Process terminate : `'Attendance' object has no attribute 'split'`

In the documentation it says 
print (attendance) # Attendance object

How to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution

i check in the github repository of pyzk and look for the attendance class and found all the object being return by the live_capture thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the attendance object into a string and split it.

```
str(attendance).split()
```

After splitting you can access the user ID and use it where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's an object of class `Attendance`. The `split()` is a method of `string`. So you can't directly split() an object. Dan is right, to split an object, first, you have to convert it to a string.

```
str(obj).split()
```

Although, you don't need to split this object to get the user id. All you have to do is, use accessor. e.g

```
user_id = attendance_obj.user_id
```